# insert data in mysql table using python script

Tags: python, mysql

1/ In the mysql database side, i got all the colomuns in the table as a varchar type

2/ I run the following python code :

```
`import mysql.connector
import csv

# Configuration de la connexion a la base de donnees MySQL
config = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'pass',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'database': 'location'

}
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# Nom de la table a vider
table_name = 'routers_status'

# Vidage de la table
truncate_query = f'TRUNCATE TABLE {table_name};'
cursor.execute(truncate_query)
cnx.commit()
cnx.commit()


query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (ip_address, longitude, latitude, hostname, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
values = ("192.168.72.2", "2.4706761837005615", "48.94111251831055", "router_1", "Up")
cursor.execute(query, values)


# Fermeture de la connexion a la base de donnees MySQL
cursor.close()
cnx.close()

print(f'Upload des donnees dans la table {table_name} termine avec succes !')
```

And i get the following error :

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column
> 'ip_address' in 'field list'

Tried using quotes in line :

```
query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (ip_address, longitude, latitude, hostname, status) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"`
```

And got this error :

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '192.168.72.2'',
> ''2.4706761837005615'', ''48.94111251831055'', ''router_1' at line 1

Can someone point the fault please? and what can i do to solve it?

Comment: Given the first error, I would verify that the table `routers_status` has a column name `ip_address`.

Comment: The colomn ip_address exists in the table, I think its more of a syntax error since when i use quotes it can get to the value

Comment: Ya, sometimes mysql will need quotes around column and table names that contain some slightly unexpected characters.